# Block free email accounts from submitting form

Tags: spam-prevention

I am having issues with spam form submissions. I set up a honeypot but are still receiving spam via free email accounts.  Whats the best way to stop free email accounts ( gmail.com , yahoo.com, hotmail.com ..etc) from being captured by my form.

Thank you!

Comment: If you stop all GMail, Yahoo, and Outlook.com users, you're not going to be left with much...Assuming you're talking about prevent bots from submitting crap to your web form, look into captchas.

Comment: Are you talking about the input field where a user can type in his email address?

Comment: My clients would like to exclude these as most emails using non-business emails are not legitimate leads.  @t.niese  - yes thats correct

Comment: This will "solve" your problem only for a short time, because the bot could enter what ever it want into the email field

Comment: I figured as much based on my research on forums. any suggestions you can provide are appreciated.